# List values in a horizontal line (php foreach)

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have this code, which works great:

```
<?php 
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT comment_count, ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0 , 30"); // NUMBER OF POSTS
foreach ($result as $topten) {
    $postid = $topten->ID;
    $title = $topten->post_title;
    $commentcount = $topten->comment_count;
    if ($commentcount != 0) {

?>

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($postid); ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a>

<?php } } ?>
```

The only problem is that it lists all values (post titles) in a vertical line.

I want them to be listed in a horizontal line, but can't get it to work.

Need help.

Comment: Seems more like a css problem than php? `a` is an inline element so they should be showing in a horizontal line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default display for **a** tag is horizontal, but maybe there is a css style that affects the default style for **a** tag.

Anyway, Try to find the parent class for all **a** tag like this:

```
    <div class="lists-a">
     <?php 
      $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT comment_count, ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0 , 30"); // NUMBER OF POSTS
         foreach ($result as $topten) {
             $postid = $topten->ID;
             $title = $topten->post_title;
             $commentcount = $topten->comment_count;
             if ($commentcount != 0) {
      ?>
       <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($postid); ?>"><?php echo $title ?></a>
   
   <?php } } ?>
```

And set css style for a tag to be listed in a horizontal line:

```
  <style>
    .lists-a a{
      display:inline;
     }
 </style>
```